# How to create undefined error but silently pass in the error console

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I am using jquery resize in my event calendar(wordpress). Most of the things are working correctly except some JS issue with the calender/list listing button.

Following is the code in jQuery resize js -

```
    add: function (l) {
        if (!e[f] && this[k]) {
            return false
        }
        var n;

        function m(s, o, p) {
            var q = $(this),
                r = $.data(this, d); // working correctly in terms of functionality if r = undefined;  

            r.w = o !== c ? o : q.width();
            r.h = p !== c ? p : q.height();

            n.apply(this, arguments)
        }
        if ($.isFunction(l)) {
            n = l;
            return m
        } else {
            n = l.handler;
            l.handler = m
        }
    }
```

If I pass `r = undefined` instead of `$.data(this, d)`, my application work smoothly but error in firebug console.
How could i silently pass this error so  that after defining r as undefined it wont pass error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just doing a check that `r` is not undefined before continuing...

```
    function m(s, o, p) {
        var q = $(this),
            r = $.data(this, d); // working correctly in terms of functionality if r = undefined;  

        if (!r) return undefined;

        r.w = o !== c ? o : q.width();
        r.h = p !== c ? p : q.height();

        n.apply(this, arguments)
    }
```

You can check the return value of `m` so that you can trap `r` being undefined.

Comment: thx for the response..I already upvoted it ..but sorry for the late acceptance :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use try and catch

```
try{

}catch(e){

}
```

Like this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbVQ8/1/) (jQuery not added). Since jQuery is not added in this jsfiddle example it should throw an error in the console, but it doesn't since it's in a try and catch block.